# Django+Ajax: Updating content without refesh

Tags: ajax, django

I am currently trying to develop a facebook clone for a uni project. I want to make a "like" button (here called "Give lasanha") and make it update without refreshing the page. So far I have been successfull in doing so, but it only updates my first post, it doesn't work for any of the other posts.

[Image of how it looks: https://i.gyazo.com/0e239fc05b401e5d1d96b6a1e08063e1.png ]

I have already tried a bunch of things, but nothing has led me to a resolution, so that is why I am writing here.

So here are my templates:
home.html (where we call the ajax script)

```
     {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.content is None %}
            <script>
                var x = '{{ post.id }}';
                $(document).ready(function (event) {
                    var x = '#lasanha'+'{{ post.id }}'
                    $(document).on('click', '#lasanha'+'{{ post.id }}', function (event) {
                        console.log( "e."+x);
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '{% url "give_lasanha" %}',
                            data: {'id':pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(response){
                                $('#lasanha_section').html(response['form'])
                            },
                        })
                    })
                })
            </script>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

```
<div id="lasanha_section" class="form-group">
                      {% include 'space/lasanha_section.html' %}
                </div>
```

lasanha_section.html

```
{{post.lasanhas.count}} Lasanha{{post.lasanhas.count|pluralize}}
<form action="{% url 'give_lasanha' %}" method="submit">
    <p id="er" value="{{post.id}}"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if is_liked %}
        <button type="submit" id="lasanha{{post.id}}" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Steal lasanha</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="lasanha{{post.id}}" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Give lasanha</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

my views.py:

```
@login_required
def give_lasanha(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    is_liked = False
    if post.lasanhas.filter(user=request.user).exists():
        post.lasanhas.remove(request.user.galaxy)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.lasanhas.add(request.user.galaxy)
        is_liked = True

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_liked': post.lasanhas.count(),
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('space/lasanha_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

And since it may be important too...
My Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stars = models.ManyToManyField(Star)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Galaxy_pics')
    lasanhas = models.ManyToManyField(Galaxy)
    content = models.TextField(null=True) #
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I believe that is every bit of code I have to share!
I am expecting that this works for every post (like in the image above), but it is only working for the first post off the page, not the others.

When I click on "Give lasanha" on the first post, the button changes to "Steal lasanha" and the counter updates to 1 Lasanhas.

When I click on one of the others, nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help.

Comment: when you say "nothing happens", I understand nothing happens on the page, but does anything change in the db? ie. are there changes to the lasanhas related to the post in the db?

Comment: I think you have a problem here: Where exactly in your template is this div with id="lasanha_section"? Is there one for entire page or one for each post? (is it in a for loop?)

Comment: Yes, it is inside a for loop that for every post creates a div like that.

Comment: ids need to be unique for the entire HTML document. You cannot have this div repeated with the same id. As you do with your buttons, where you give them a unique id by appending the `post.id` you also should do that with this div (and use that id in your script).

Comment: oh my god that was it!! Thank you so much!